# What is the bottom button called in the navigation bar, that you sometime see for changing settings

Tags: java, android

[image]

How is that yellow circled button called and how can I make it show?

Comment: Don't do it - it's really obsolete design pattern which was used for compatibility with old Android versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the legacy overflow button. It's required so that old apps can run on newer devices without a hardware menu button.

> - If you set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to 11 or higher, the system will not add the legacy overflow button.
> - Otherwise, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running on Android 3.0 or higher.
> - The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower, set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Consider designing your apps so that you don't need the legacy overflow.